# Best way to return the key of an array about the value of one of its containing objects

Tags: javascript

I would like to know what is the better way to exectute this common action:

```
var id = 1;
var Players = [{ id: 0, other: '...'}, { id: 1, other: '...' }]

for (var i=0; i<Players.length; i++) {
  if (Players[i].id == id) {
    return i;
  } 
}
```

I was thinking about Array.map but i don't know if we can access the key:

```
Players.map(function(Player) { if (Player.id == id) { return ?? } });
```

Comment: So you just want to find the index of an item that matches some criteria (matching `id` in this case)?

Comment: What is it that you want to be better? Performance? Simplicity? Reusability? Maintainability?

Comment: @Ian: But that returns the matching item, not the index. However, it's not clear whether the OP really needs the index, or just the item.

Comment: @MattBurland No you're right, it seems they want the index. And that's what I was shooting for but obviously did it wrongly :)

Comment: *"I was thinking about Array.map but i don't know if we can access the key"* Sure, just take the time to [read the documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map), and you'll see that you can access the index via the second argument passed to the callback. `Players.map(function(Player, i) {...`

Comment: Here's a dirty one using `map`: http://jsfiddle.net/pwrL7/1/

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your structure (and keeping performance in mind); making it an associative object/array could work out.

```
var object = { id: 1, other: '...' };

var Players = [];
Players[object.id] = object;
```

You can then reference the required Player by ID by doing:

```
var id = 1;
var playerObject = Players[id];
```

Please note that you cannot use negative or zero values for the ID in this case.

Answer (score 1):

You could also try [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce):

```
// The second argument is set to null so that reduce doesn't just
// start with the first object in the array
Players.reduce(function(memo, Player, key) {
    return Player.id === id ? key : memo;
}, null);
```

Answer (score 0):

`Array.map()` passes the index as the second parameter to the callback.
However, it won't help you find a single item.

Javascript arrays do not have a function that does this.

Using [LoDash](http://lodash.com/), you can do this very easily:

```
_.findIndex(Players, { id: 4 })
```